# Openshift cannot connect to localhost during start

Tags: docker, openshift

After installation OpenShift on Ubuntu 16.04 I try to run it and get error as below:

```
koziolek@koziolek-desktop ~ $ oc cluster up
Getting a Docker client ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11 is available ...
Pulling image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11
E0116 20:25:45.193436   29023 helper.go:179] Reading docker config from /home/koziolek/.docker/config.json failed: open /home/koziolek/.docker/config.json: no such file or directory, will attempt to pull image d
ocker.io/openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11 anonymously
Pulled 1/5 layers, 21% complete                                   
Pulled 2/5 layers, 58% complete
Pulled 3/5 layers, 64% complete         
Pulled 3/5 layers, 76% complete          
Pulled 3/5 layers, 91% complete
Pulled 4/5 layers, 99% complete                                       
Pulled 5/5 layers, 100% complete               
Extracting                                                       
Image pull complete                                              
Pulling image openshift/origin-cli:v3.11                         
E0116 20:27:50.037777   29023 helper.go:179] Reading docker config from /home/koziolek/.docker/config.json failed: open /home/koziolek/.docker/config.json: no such file or directory, will attempt to pull image d
ocker.io/openshift/origin-cli:v3.11 anonymously            
Image pull complete
Pulling image openshift/origin-node:v3.11
E0116 20:27:52.821025   29023 helper.go:179] Reading docker config from /home/koziolek/.docker/config.json failed: open /home/koziolek/.docker/config.json: no such file or directory, will attempt to pull image d
ocker.io/openshift/origin-node:v3.11 anonymously                                 
Pulled 5/6 layers, 84% complete           
Pulled 5/6 layers, 94% complete
Pulled 6/6 layers, 100% complete
Extracting                  
Image pull complete
Creating shared mount directory on the remote host ...
Determining server IP ...   
Checking if OpenShift is already running ...
Checking for supported Docker version (=>1.22) ...
Checking if insecured registry is configured properly in Docker ...
Checking if required ports are available ...
Checking if OpenShift client is configured properly ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11 is available ...
Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11 ...
I0116 20:28:55.880105   29023 flags.go:30] Running "create-kubelet-flags"
I0116 20:28:56.862581   29023 run_kubelet.go:49] Running "start-kubelet"
I0116 20:28:57.106578   29023 run_self_hosted.go:181] Waiting for the kube-apiserver to be ready ...
I0116 20:30:17.115655   29023 interface.go:26] Installing "kube-proxy" ...
I0116 20:30:17.115674   29023 interface.go:26] Installing "kube-dns" ...
I0116 20:30:17.115682   29023 interface.go:26] Installing "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator" ...
I0116 20:30:17.115690   29023 interface.go:26] Installing "openshift-apiserver" ...
I0116 20:30:17.115713   29023 apply_template.go:81] Installing "openshift-apiserver"
I0116 20:30:17.115844   29023 apply_template.go:81] Installing "kube-dns" 
I0116 20:30:17.115848   29023 apply_template.go:81] Installing "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator"
I0116 20:30:17.115854   29023 apply_template.go:81] Installing "kube-proxy"
I0116 20:30:18.924195   29023 interface.go:41] Finished installing "kube-proxy" "kube-dns" "openshift-service-cert-signer-operator" "openshift-apiserver"
Error: Get https://127.0.0.1:8443/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1/apiservices: unexpected EOF
koziolek@koziolek-desktop ~ $ oc login -u system:admin           
Server [https://localhost:8443]:                                 
error: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused - verify you have provided the correct host and port and that the server is currently running.
```

When I check cluster status i get:

```
koziolek@koziolek-desktop ~ $ oc cluster status                                 
Error: invalid configuration: Missing or incomplete configuration info.  Please login or point to an existing, complete config file:

  1. Via the command-line flag --config                                                                          
  2. Via the KUBECONFIG environment variable                                                             
  3. In your home directory as ~/.kube/config                                                                 

To view or setup config directly use the 'config' command.
```

But restarting cluster via `oc cluster up` returns erroe – cluster already up.

I have docker network configuration as below:

```
koziolek@koziolek-desktop ~ $ docker network inspect -f "{{range .IPAM.Config }}{{ .Subnet }}{{end}}" bridge                                                                                                       
172.17.0.0/16
```

and firewall configuration as described in [instruction](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/v4.0.0-alpha.0/docs/cluster_up_down.md#getting-started).

My question is what I missed in configuration?

Comment: are you still experiencing the issue?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli yes :(

Comment: similar to the docs you've sent, are you using version 4.0.0-alpha? if so why not the newer releases like [4.8](https://github.com/openshift/origin/tree/release-4.8) or [4.9](https://github.com/openshift/origin/tree/release-4.9)? also, please add `docker ps` output.

Comment: @NoamYizraeli… thanks… Update all stuff on machine fix that.

Comment: so you've used one of the updated versions and it fixed it? if so which one?

Comment: Newest. 2h of updating PC. Update oc, docker, kernel... steam... and many more

Comment:  happy to hear it at least eventually worked out, though would be better if you had figured out what it was